# A non-null String must be provided to a Text widget Flutter Api

Tags: api, flutter

Container(
child: Text(data[index]['vote_average'])

Vote_avarage is an int.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try

```
Container( child: Text(data[index]['vote_average'].toString())
```

Answer (score 0):

I think according to the title: "A non-null String must be provided to a Text widget Flutter Api", the problem may be that **data[index]['vote_average']** returns null.

You may consider debugging **data** object :)